# Is there a difference between one executor vs multiple executors on a Jenkins slave where only one build should run at a time?

Tags: jenkins, executors

I have a jenkins setup with 1 master and 4 slaves. Each slave is dedicated to building something specific (iOS, Android, etc...). One of the slaves is dedicated to a couple of jobs that each take about an hour to run. The slave is configured with 4 executors, and the two jobs each have a weight of 3. I understand that this ensures that only one of the jobs will run on the slave at a time.

However, would it make a difference if I configured the slave to have 1 executor and give each job a weight of 1? These are the only two jobs that run on this slave. Does more executors/weight mean more CPU power is used for the job? If there is only 1 executor and the job weight is 1, will it increase the amount of time that the build takes?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to configure your master/slave like this:

- Dynamic slave creation in docker images.
- Configure each slave with one executor and configure to build all your technologies, don't limit a slave for Android, another for iOS....

Doing it, you wouldn't be these type of problems and scalability is better.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not answer my question about executors and job weight.